# How do I create a sample from a previous sample of a data frame

Tags: r

I created a data frame with two variables: one with characters(teams)and one numeric. I'd like to do a complete random sample to choose two teams and then another sample between the two elected to get just one. Finally I'd like to repeat this without the first two elected teams, being able to replicate it.
I have tried with this code. However, when it comes to the second sample the election is not from the two elected teams, but from two other teams.

```
teams <- c('madrid','barcelona','psg','mancunited','mancity','juve')
mean  <- c(14, 14.5, 13, 10, 13.4, 13.7)
df    <- data.frame(teams, stats)
x     <- 1:nrow(df)


a1 <- df[sample((x),2),]
y  <- sample(c(a1[1,1], a1[2,1]), 1, 
           prob = c((a1[1,2]/(a1[1,2]+a1[2,2])), (a1[2,2]/(a1[1,2]+a1[2,2]))))
A1 <- df[y,]
A1

df <- df[!(df$teams==a1[1,1] | df$teams==a1[2,1]),]
x  <- 1:nrow(df)

b1 <- df[sample((x),2),]
B1 <- df[sample(c(b1[1,1], b1[2,1]), 1,  
                prob = c((b1[1,2]/(b1[1,2]+b1[2,2])), (b1[2,2]/(b1[1,2]+b1[2,2])))),]
B1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
#Choose two teams
random_2_x <- sample(x, 2)
#Chose one out of the above two
random_2_1_x <- sample(random_2_x, 1)

#Chose two from the one not in random_2_x
random_2_y <- sample(x[-random_2_x], 2)
#Chose one out of the above two
random_2_y_1 <- sample(random_2_y, 1)
```

You can use these indexes to subset from dataframe :

```
df[random_2_x, ]
#       teams mean
#4 mancunited 10.0
#6       juve 13.7

df[random_2_1_x, ]
#  teams mean
#6  juve 13.7

df[random_2_y, ]
#      teams mean
#1    madrid 14.0
#2 barcelona 14.5

df[random_2_y_1, ]
#      teams mean
#2 barcelona 14.5
```

**data**

```
df<- data.frame(teams, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `stats` column for weighting the probability of selection on the second draw (choosing 1 team from the 2 already selected), you can use the following function. The `prob` argument of `sample` can be a vector of probability *weights*. So you don't need to calculate actual proportions manually - just provide the `stats` column and R will do what you want.

```
game <- function(df){
  x     <- 1:nrow(df)
  a1 <-  df[sample((x),2),]
  y1  <- sample(a1$teams, 1, prob = a1$stats)

  df2 <- df[!(df$teams %in% a1$teams),]
  x  <- 1:nrow(df2)
  b1 <- df2[sample(x,2),]
  y2  <- sample(b1$teams, 1, prob = b1$stats)

  c(y1, y2)
}
```

Here's your data:

```
teams <- c('madrid','barcelona','psg','mancunited','mancity','juve')
stats  <- c(14, 14.5, 13, 10, 13.4, 13.7)
df    <- data.frame(teams, stats) # R 4.0.0 no need to convert strings to factors.
```

Replicate 10,000 games:

```
games <- t(replicate(10000, game(df)))

head(games)
#      [,1]        [,2]        
# [1,] "barcelona" "mancity"   
# [2,] "madrid"    "mancunited"
# [3,] "madrid"    "psg"       
# [4,] "juve"      "psg"       
# [5,] "mancity"   "barcelona" 
# [6,] "mancity"   "juve"
```

You can see the proportion of times each team got selected in each of your phases.

```
sort(prop.table(table(games[,1])), decr = TRUE) # phase 1

# barcelona     madrid        psg       juve    mancity mancunited 
#    0.1797     0.1787     0.1687     0.1677     0.1663     0.1389

sort(prop.table(table(games[,1])), decr = TRUE) # phase 2

# madrid  barcelona       juve    mancity        psg mancunited 
# 0.1826     0.1755     0.1691     0.1670     0.1663     0.1395
```